# Start Dialog after Direct Line

Tags: node.js, botframework, slack, direct-line-botframework

My use case is this.

- The bot will send the user a 'DM' via the Direct Line API
- Upon receipt of the DM, bot should start a dialog to the user to ask user a few questions
- Once questioning is done, bot pings back at original channel/room

How does one 'receive' a Direct Line message? And how do you start a dialog out of nothing?

Comment: Can you explain what the "Direct Line API" is? Maybe link to its documentation? The only API I know for this is Slack's web API, where [`im.open`](https://api.slack.com/methods/im.open) is the way to start a direct message conversation with a user.

Comment: Ah, found it: http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/restapi-directline/. It's part of Microsoft's "Bot Framework." Sorry, I don't have relevant experience here.

Answer (score 0):

For more information on how to use Direct Line to interact with Bot Framework bots, check out the repository here: [Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS).

For example, to post a message to your bot, you would send a Direct Line message like this:

```
directLine.postActivity({
    from: { id: 'myUserId', name: 'myUserName' }, //required (from.name is optional)
    type: 'message',
    text: 'a message for you, Rudy'
}).subscribe(
    id => console.log("Posted activity, assigned ID ", id),
    error => console.log("Error posting activity", error)
);
```

You can also find a [Direct Line client/server example for Node SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-DirectLine) in the [BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) repo.